# Передать текст для печати в делегат (консольное приложение)

Tags: c#

```
 class Print {
        Transfer Transf;

        public Print(Transfer Tr)
        {
            Transf = Tr;
            PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();
            printDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(PD_PrintPage);
            printDoc.Print();
        }

        private void PD_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {

            string PrintText = 1\r\n";
            PrintText += "2\r\n";
            PrintText += "3\r\n";
            PrintText += "3";
            Font PrintFont = new Font("Times New Roman", 3, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Millimeter);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(PrintText, PrintFont, Brushes.Black, new PointF(0, 0));
        }
    }
```

Вот есть пример, как вывести на печать текст, а как передать в  PD_PrintPage мою структуру Transfer?

Comment: Ну так она объявлена за пределами печатающего метода и доступна в нем. Просто используйте `Transf...`

Comment: Вообще пример очень странный (причем на MSDN такой же). Мы подписываемся на событие печати и даём команду "печатай". А потом когда нам говорят я уже вот-вот начну печатать, пытаемся сформировать какой-то документ. А что будет если подписчиков несколько? А если для формирования документа требуется некоторое время?

Comment: Дак откуда я его взял то =) Вот я и разбираюсь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда вы создаете экземпляр класса `Print`, то в конструкторе уже передаете эту структуру и заносите её в свойство `Transfer Transf`. Достаточно просто ею и воспользоваться в методе:

```
private void PD_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    // Тут свойство Transf ДОСТУПНО!!
    // Так как оно находится в том же классе
    // Можно обращаться к нему без проблем

    Transf.MY_DATA - доступны для действий (если не ограничены модификатором доступа)
}
```